# How can I do when I make a $\log_2$ towards zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, linear-algebra, density-operator

Good day,

I want to make a measurement on qubit by using formula von Neumann entropy using Mathematica given as below;

$$S(\rho)=-Tr(\rho \log_2\rho)$$

The 
$$
\rho=\left(\array{0.5&0\\0&0.5} \right)
$$

My problem is, when I make the

$$
\log_2\left(\array{0.5&0\\0&0.5} \right)
$$

I get the output

$$\left(\array{-1&∞\\∞&-1} \right)$$

How can I deal with this value in my measurement since it cannot be calculated?

Comment: The log of a matrix is not just the log of its entries! In the case that the matrix is diagonalizable, you just take the log of the diagonal.

Comment: From the formula, it mean I can Tr(ρ) x Tr(log2ρ) differently instead of I do the operation of ρlog2ρ then Trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action of a function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ on a diagonal matrix is, by definition,
$$
f\begin{pmatrix}a_1& 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & a_2 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & a_n\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}f(a_1)& 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & f(a_2) & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & f(a_n)\end{pmatrix}.
$$
(For more details see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function) and similar resources.) You therefore need to take the logarithm only on the diagonal.

It's also important to note that $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho)\times\mathrm{Tr}(\log_2(\rho))$ will yield the wrong answer here - you just can't break up a trace into two different traces; that's a fundamental misunderstanding of how the trace works. The logarithm $\log_2(\rho)$ is a matrix, which you need to matrix-multiply with $\rho$ and *then* take the trace. If any of this isn't obvious, then you are probably rather out of your depth and you should really spend some time revising the basics.